# Is there any standard to validate user input in php?

Tags: php, validation

Every where i find this "Never ever (ever) trust foreign input". They ask to validate every user input. But i am not sure what i should validate. Is there any standard to validate user input  if the user enter any malicious code? Actually I want to know what this malicious code might be and how to validate?

After doing a little research i found a standard password.php for password validation, `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` for email and `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` for url validation. But for other input forms like name, textarea, phone number, username etc is there any standard to validate?

Comment: I think whether an input is invalid or not depends on how do _you_ expect it to be and how are _you_ planning to use it later.

Comment: Well, one reason to not trust user input: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: well, how i expect it comes later. But i have to make sure first that user did not enter any malicious input to attack my site. Then i will do the other validation as i need.

Comment: @TiesonT. you mean don't allow users to input anything? Instead say sanitize the inputs

Comment: There's nothing malicious inherently, but it depends on where it's used. a '<script>...' input does nothing to a database for example but can have your cookies stolen if outputted on a page

Comment: You should read the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info) of [tag:php] tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **validate** input based on your business rules (e-mail validation is such case).
You should **escape** output based on your output media - when you sending data to browser you are escaping HTML, when you are sending to database - you are escaping db specific characters, etc.

Comment: Agree, but with a correction. "db specific characters" is a common misconception. There are no "db specific characters". There are different formatting rules for the different query parts.

Answer (score 2):

Everything need to be validated according to your project and use-case needs.
There are no standart perfect validation solution in native PHP.
You can use excellent **Zend validators** collection (even without Zend) http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html
That's a nice choice because they are really powerfull, and contain all you need now and all you'll ever need in future.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no standard to validate user input.

Every single value have to be validated separately, based on it's meaning and future use.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse validation with sanization. Previous answers are all excellent but I'd just liked to point out that validation should take place when you need the user input to be in specific format. Emails are emails so you can send email to an valid email address (although the address is not necessarily an active address). And numbers are numbers so the input can be inserted into database's `integer`/`float` column without problems.

Some validation tasks also help to keep your database/application (like validating integers) safe. But how to validate free text, telephone numbers, postal addresses etc.? This kind of input you need to sanitize most of the times. Escape special characters or make sure user's malicious `DELETE *` kind of input doesn't get executed.

Also a word for people who like to validate (not sanitize) telephone numbers, postal addresses etc. Internet is global (duh, really...). Don't be too eager to limit users input by using too strict validation rules according to your countrys formatting rules. As a native Finn I've had many occasions where strict formatting rules are extremely annoying and sometimes they have also made impossible to give correct information because the coder thinks he's been extra clever defining the strict format that has to be an correct address format everyone because it's a correct format for his address.